# Is there any way to take the user's input in one variable and use that input in another variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to take the user's input in one variable and use that input in another variable?

For example:

```
def user_input():
    numb = input("Please input the number ")
    numb_process()

def numb_process():
    if numb == '1':
        print("Good")
    else:
        print("Bad")

user_input()
```

Comment: It's called argument passing. In short, define `numb_process` as `def numb_process(numb):` and call it with `numb_process(numb)`.

Comment: Exactly. Just continue reading whatever Python tutorial you're following for two or three more pages. You will inevitably be introduced to arguments to methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is python 101 and the standard [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is a good place to learn basic concepts. In your case, simple parameter passing will do.

```
def user_input():
    numb = input("Input number ") # bind result of the input function
                                  # to local variable "numb"

    numb_process(numb)            # pass the object bound to "numb"
                                  # to called function

def numb_process(some_number):    # bind inbound object to local variable
                                  # "some_number"

    if some_number == '1':        # use bound object in calculations
        print("Good")
    else:
        print("Bad")

user_input()
```

Comment: Hey this worked however could you explain to me what you did here please? 

By doing (numb) at the end did you bring the numb over to the other variable?

Comment: `user_input` passes the object it got from `input` to `numb_process`. I changed the local name in the second function to make it clear that it has no idea what the object is named in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. You can call the numb_process function by giving it an argument "numb" that will move from the function "user_input" to function "numb_process".

```
def user_input():
    numb = input("Please input the number ")
    numb_process(numb)

def numb_process(numb):
    if numb == '1':
        print("Good")
    else:
        print("Bad")

user_input()
```

Comment: Could you explain how and/or why? The OP clearly doesn't know very much, and just dumping a working example in doesn't teach them anything.

Comment: Thanks for heads up, I am still pretty new.